# GetMethod and invoke it via Reflection passing Object[] as param

Tags: java

I have the following code snippet which throws exception, the problem seem to be with the parameter which I'm trying to pass to 'foo' method.

```
public void test() {
   try {
        Class<?>[] paramType = new Class[] { Object[].class };

        Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("foo", paramType);

        Object tt = (Object)new String("TEST");

        m.invoke(this, new Object[] { tt });

    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void foo(Object[] params) {
    System.out.println("ffffoooooo" + params);
}
```

**EXCEPTION:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at reflection.MyReflection.invokeMethod(MyReflection.java:50)
at reflection.MyReflection.main(MyReflection.java:20)
```

Can some spot my mistake??

Comment: can you give the stacktrace ?

Comment: Well what exception is being thrown? Please show the complete stack trace. *Any* time you ask a question about code which is failing, *always* provide the error.

Comment: Try  Object[] tt = new Object[] { new String("TEST") };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Method.invoke` method takes an `Object[]` parameter which corresponds to the arguments you want to provide.

As you've got a single parameter which is of type `Object[]`, you need to wrap that in *another* `Object[]`. For example:

```
m.invoke(this, new Object[] { new Object[] { tt } });
```

Or you could use the fact that it's a varargs parameter on `invoke`:

```
Object argument = new Object[] { tt };
m.invoke(this, argument);
```

Note that the compile-time type of `argument` being `Object` rather than `Object[]` is important here, in order to make the compiler create the array due to varargs. If you declare `argument` to be of type `Object[]`, the compiler won't wrap it in another array.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
m.invoke(this, (Object) new Object[] { tt });
```

[`Method#invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) declares a [variable arity parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) of type `Object`. So the `Object[]` argument you pass to it binds to that parameter. The `invoke` method then uses what is in the array to invoke the corresponding method. That is, it tries to invoke

```
this.foo(tt);
```

which obviously is wrong.

By casting the argument to `Object`, Java implicitly wraps the argument list (that single argument) in a `Object[]` and passes that to `Method#invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass an Object[] as a parameter, but Method.invoke requires a Object[] for all parameters.  Try this:

```
    Object tt = (Object)new String("TEST");
    Object[] param = new Object[] { tt };
    Object[] params = new Object[] { param };
    m.invoke(this, params);
```